# How can I make TypeScript null check follow Jest expect response?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am using Jest as unit test framework for TypeScript code. Below is the code:

```
const result: User|null = getResult();
expect(result).not.toBeNull();
expect(result.name).toBe('Joey');  // typescript compiles `result` could be null here.
```

The `result` can be either `User` type or `null`. But the next `expect` already ensure it is not null. But TypeScript still complains about the last statement. Is there a way to let TypeScript respect Jest expect?

Comment: `expect(value).not.toBeNull()` isn't a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions); the result isn't known until runtime. Just `expect(result?.name).toBe('Joey');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the non-null assertion operator (!) to tell TypeScript that a value is not null. For example:

```
const result: User|null = getResult();
expect(result).not.toBeNull();
expect(result!.name).toBe('Joey');
```

Or you could also add an additional check to make sure that `result` is not null before accessing its name property like:

```
const result: User|null = getResult();
expect(result).not.toBeNull();
if (result) {
  expect(result.name).toBe('Joey');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import assert from 'assert'

const result: User|null = getResult();
expect(result).not.toBeNull();
assert(result) // or: assert(result !== null)
expect(result.name).toBe('Joey');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.